# Adding listener to Zoomin OpenSeaDragon

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

Is there a way to add a listener to the ZoomIn button in **OpenSeaDragon**? I am not sure if my ZoomIn button is being clicked so I want to intercept the click with a listener.

I have looked at the API but it doesn't seem to show a list of event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
viewer.zoomInButton.tracker.clickHandler = function() {
    console.log('click');
};
```